# iOS schemes/build configurations and git

Tags: ios, git, configuration, build, gitignore

I have created two additional schemes to my iOS project, and two build configurations. When I push the changes to my remote github repository the schemes and build configurations are not added. Should I refactor my gitignore file?

Comment: .DS_Store
*/build/*
*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
!default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
!default.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3
xcuserdata
profile
*.moved-aside
DerivedData
.idea/
*.hmap
*.xccheckout